# how to recognize the kind of object we intrest in picture

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

this is a picture of a dog's contour and a horse's contour 
[alt text http://www.tlnews.cn/forum/attachments/month_0810/20081024_2f055de790b83aced18atjm8EVN4Gyay.jpg](http://www.tlnews.cn/forum/attachments/month_0810/20081024_2f055de790b83aced18atjm8EVN4Gyay.jpg)

how to make computer know it is a horse or a dog or a person.
[alt text http://www.pocketgo.com.cn/upload/2008-10/122465306490637600.jpg](http://www.pocketgo.com.cn/upload/2008-10/122465306490637600.jpg)

Comment: Let us know when your artificial intelligence is completed, so the Nobel committee can create a new Computer Science category!

Comment: I think it is not very different, computer can recognize people from million face database, so I think it will be easy to recognize the kind of object.

Comment: The Optical Horse Recognition (OHR) field is still a bit immature.  We're definitely making progress, though.

Comment: Very bright people have been working for decades on finding a general solution for that problem and haven's succeeded. So you can safely assume it's not "easy to recognize the kind of object".

Comment: I'm going to join the chorus and say THIS IS A VERY HARD PROBLEM!!! You are going to need to read couple of research papers on object recognition if you are even going to start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will help
http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/pdfs/SIFTflow.pdf

Answer (score 0):

That's a difficult question.

You should research [computer vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision).

I would think the method would be something like:

- Find edges (just image processsing)
- Trace shapes (not sure how to go about doing that)
- Pass to neural network for classification.

Of course, designing and training the network is not exactly a simple operation..